# What applications are available to Ubuntu for Android?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

I was checking this Ubuntu for Android stuff.

Is it an Android system, meaning that I can install basically any app from Google Play or does it have specific applications?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Ubuntu for Android currently. It requires vendor buy-in to implement on a device.

However, it is a system by which Android and Ubuntu are both on the device. You would use Android when using the device normally, and it would switch to Ubuntu when docked to a keyboard/mouse.